# how to deploy spring boot war in jboss(version 5) server?

Tags: spring-boot, jboss5.x

## Exception while deploying spring boot War in JBoss server.

I have created a sample application class which loads all spring boot configurations.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

controller class:

```
    @RequestMapping("/hello/{name}")
        String hello(@PathVariable String name) {
            return "Hello, " + name + "!";
        }
```

Here is my web.xml

```
<web-app>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>demo.Application</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.boot.legacy.context.web.SpringBootContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

when I deploy this as a war, i am getting below exception:

```
2016-06-15 11:47:39,390 +0530 level=INFO  class=org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment              deploy, ctxPath=/spring-boot-demo
2016-06-15 11:47:39,499 +0530 level=ERROR class=STDERR              SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
2016-06-15 11:47:39,500 +0530 level=ERROR class=STDERR              SLF4J: Found binding in [vfszip:/Users/xxx/Downloads/softwares/whp-jboss-web-5/common/lib/slf4j-jboss-logging.jar/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
2016-06-15 11:47:39,500 +0530 level=ERROR class=STDERR              SLF4J: Found binding in [vfszip:/Users/xxx/Downloads/softwares/whp-jboss-web-5/server/default/deploy/spring-boot-demo.war/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.1.5.jar/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
2016-06-15 11:47:39,500 +0530 level=ERROR class=STDERR              SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
2016-06-15 11:47:39,542 +0530 level=ERROR class=STDERR              SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
2016-06-15 11:47:42,077 +0530 level=INFO  class=STDOUT                .   ____          _            __ _ _
2016-06-15 11:47:42,077 +0530 level=INFO  class=STDOUT               /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
2016-06-15 11:47:42,077 +0530 level=INFO  class=STDOUT              ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
2016-06-15 11:47:42,077 +0530 level=INFO  class=STDOUT               \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
2016-06-15 11:47:42,077 +0530 level=INFO  class=STDOUT                '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
2016-06-15 11:47:42,077 +0530 level=INFO  class=STDOUT               =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
2016-06-15 11:47:42,079 +0530 level=INFO  class=STDOUT               :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.3.RELEASE)
2016-06-15 11:47:42,140 +0530 level=INFO  class=org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/spring-boot-demo]              Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-06-15 11:47:42,148 +0530 level=INFO  class=STDOUT              2016-06-15 11:47:42.146  INFO 2543 --- [      HDScanner] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1465971462146 ms
2016-06-15 11:47:42,152 +0530 level=INFO  class=STDOUT              2016-06-15 11:47:42.152  INFO 2543 --- [      HDScanner] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Starting application on BANL12f516590.local with PID 2543 (/Users/xxx/Downloads/softwares/whp-jboss-web-5/server/default/deploy/spring-boot-demo.war started by psudheendra in /Users/xxx/Downloads/softwares/whp-jboss-web-5)
2016-06-15 11:47:42,152 +0530 level=INFO  class=STDOUT              2016-06-15 11:47:42.152  INFO 2543 --- [      HDScanner] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : The following profiles are active: dev
2016-06-15 11:47:42,177 +0530 level=INFO  class=STDOUT              2016-06-15 11:47:42.177  INFO 2543 --- [      HDScanner] onConfigNonEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.legacy.context.web.AnnotationConfigNonEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@42bf31dc: startup date [Wed Jun 15 11:47:42 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-06-15 11:47:42,222 +0530 level=INFO  class=STDOUT              2016-06-15 11:47:42.222 ERROR 2543 --- [      HDScanner] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver$VfsResourceMatchingDelegate.findMatchingResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:736) ~[spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.findPathMatchingResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:420) ~[spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.getResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:274) ~[spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getResources(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1269) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext.getResources(GenericApplicationContext.java:225) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:270) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:248) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:137) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:268) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:137) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:268) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:232) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:199) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:168) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:321) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.legacy.context.web.SpringBootContextLoaderListener.initWebApplicationContext(SpringBootContextLoaderListener.java:61) ~[spring-boot-legacy-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3910) [jbossweb.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4389) [jbossweb.jar!/:na]
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:313) [jboss-web-service.jar!/:5.1.2 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_2 date=201111102209)]
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:145) [jboss-web-service.jar!/:5.1.2 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_2 date=201111102209)]
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461) [jboss.jar!/:5.1.2 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_2 date=201207160006)]
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:122) [jboss.jar!/:5.1.2 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_2 date=201207160006)]
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97) [jboss.jar!/:5.1.2 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_2 date=201207160006)]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157) [jboss-mbeans.jar!/:5.1.2 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_2 date=201207160006)]
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96) [jboss-mbeans.jar!/:5.1.2 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_2 date=201111102209)]
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88) [jboss-mbeans.jar!/:5.1.2 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_2 date=201111102209)]
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264) [jboss-mbeans.jar!/:5.1.2 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_2 date=201111102209)]
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668) [jboss-jmx.jar!/:5.1.2 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_2 date=201111102209)]
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206) [jboss-system-jmx.jar!/:5.1.2 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_2 date=201207160006)]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.start(Unknown Source) [na:na]
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42) [jboss-system-jmx.jar!/:5.1.2 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_2 date=201207160006)]
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37) [jboss-system-jmx.jar!/:5.1.2 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_2 date=201207160006)]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:297) [jboss-system-jmx.jar!/:5.1.2 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_2 date=201207160006)]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:826) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:826) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:556) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688) [jboss-system-jmx.jar!/:5.1.2 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_2 date=201207160006)]
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460) [jboss-system-jmx.jar!/:5.1.2 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_2 date=201207160006)]
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163) [jboss-system-jmx.jar!/:5.1.2 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_2 date=201207160006)]
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99) [jboss-system-jmx.jar!/:5.1.2 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_2 date=201207160006)]
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46) [jboss-system-jmx.jar!/:5.1.2 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_2 date=201207160006)]
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62) [jboss-deployers-spi.jar!/:2.0.10.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55) [jboss-deployers-spi.jar!/:2.0.10.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [jboss-deployers-impl.jar!/:2.0.10.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1454) [jboss-deployers-impl.jar!/:2.0.10.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1172) [jboss-deployers-impl.jar!/:2.0.10.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1193) [jboss-deployers-impl.jar!/:2.0.10.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1113) [jboss-deployers-impl.jar!/:2.0.10.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:826) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:556) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:789) [jboss-deployers-impl.jar!/:2.0.10.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:699) [jboss-deployers-impl.jar!/:2.0.10.GA]
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117) [jboss-system.jar!/:5.1.2 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_2 date=201207160006)]
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:409) [jboss-system.jar!/:5.1.2 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_2 date=201207160006)]
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:294) [jboss-system.jar!/:5.1.2 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_2 date=201207160006)]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not detect JBoss VFS infrastructure
        at org.springframework.core.io.VfsUtils.(VfsUtils.java:94) ~[spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        ... 86 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.vfs.VFS from BaseClassLoader@33fb67db{vfszip:/Users/xxx/Downloads/softwares/whp-jboss-web-5/server/default/deploy/spring-boot-demo.war/}
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:477) ~[jboss-classloader.jar:2.0.10.GA]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at org.springframework.core.io.VfsUtils.(VfsUtils.java:71) ~[spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        ... 86 common frames omitted
```

Dependencies in pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-legacy</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Where is your question body?

Comment: how to deploy spring boot war in jboss(version 5) server?

Comment: Done, is it fine now?

Comment: Please read this page http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and see an example of a good question like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array

Comment: Thanks for your help. is it fine now?

Comment: JBoss has a history of being a bit brain dead about scanning the classpath and sometimes fails when it tries to load something that most other app servers don't even look at. That appears to be what's happening here. It's tripping up trying to load `org/crsh/plugin/PluginLifeCycle`. What dependencies does your app have? Are you trying to use `spring-boot-starter-remote-shell`?

Comment: No, I am not using spring-boot-starter-remote shell. Here are my dependencies - spring-boot-starter-web(excluded spring-boot-starter-tomcat), spring-boot-legacy in my POM.xml

Comment: For whatever reason it thinks it needs to use the VFS infrastructure instead of regular loading. The trigger is the `vfs` part in the URL. However that only works (afaik) on JBoss 6+ and not on earlier versions. This might be a regression in Spring or the minimum version to use Spring 4.2 is JBoss6. Actually it is 6.1 as of Spring 4.0 see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/migrating-from-earlier-versions-of-the-spring-framework#servers .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to run a Spring 4.2 application on a non supported JBoss server version. Since Spring 4.0 the minimum JBoss version is 6.1, see the [migration from earlier version of the spring framework](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/migrating-from-earlier-versions-of-the-spring-framework#servers) section on the wiki.